# how to check uncheck multiple items in CheckBoxList based on DataTable value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have `CheckBoxList` I want to Check multiple items based on database value 
here is my code

```
String TargetQuery = "Select RoleID from t_Et_Role_Staff_Combination where  EmployeeID='" + EmployeeID + "'";    
SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(TargetQuery, DBcon.con);        
DataTable dtcheck = new DataTable();
adapt.Fill(dtcheck);

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    for (int i = 0; i < dtcheck.Rows.Count; i++)
    {    
        CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue = dtcheck.Rows[i][0].ToString();        
    }
}
```

but this checked only one item( the last item) from `DataTable`  the previous items are not selected

[based on my database value `administrator` and `aaa` should be checked but now only `aaa` is selected]

[image]

Comment: CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue for each iteration of your for loop you are setting value to the same CheckBox whose name is CheckBoxList1

Comment: Every `CheckBoxList` item has a Boolean flag `Selected`. Use this.

Comment: thank you but its Checkboxlist not checkbox. it has multiple items. i want to check by item value

Comment: Is your Checkboxlist selection mode is MultiExtended or single ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate inside Checkboklist items not in datatable.

```
if (dtcheck != null && dtcheck.Rows.Count > 0) /* Prevents from null reference exception */
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if ( i < dtcheck.Rows.Count) /* Ensure and prevents from Index out of range exception */
        {
            bool flag = default(bool);
            Boolean.TryParse(dtcheck.Rows[i][0].ToString(), out flag);
            CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected = flag;
        }
    }
}
```

Since you have updated your post and rest of detail above mentioned code won't work in that case. As mentioned your database value is **administrator** but your checkboxlist text is **Administrator** both are different you need something like following that matches the text and ignore the case.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtcheck.Rows.Count; i++)
{    
    string compareText = dtcheck.Rows[i][0].ToString();
    var vCheckBoxItem = CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text.Equals(compareText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
    if (vCheckBoxItem != null)
        vCheckBoxItem.Selected = true;      
}
```

Comment: its not working CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Checked = flag;   .checked is not recognize.

Comment: @user3536676: After seeing your updated code I have updated my post. Try it, Hope this works for you.

Comment: Sorry, It's not **Checked** actually it's **Selected**.

Comment: thank you  still not working but i used value not Items Name

Comment: Can you just share markup for checkboxlist and how you are binding checkboxlist and what data does datatable have?